# tabularx add vertical border line in merged cell

Tags: tabularx

I'd like to draw vertical border lines in merged cells, but now merged cells do not have any vertical border line.

How can I add lines?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{policy}
\label{tab:mutationoperators}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|L|}
\hline
ope                 & Description               \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Category1 }               \\\hline
  d                       &       d                    \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Category2}                \\\hline
                     f    &         f                  \\\hline
                       f  &         f                  \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Category3}                \\\hline
                     f    &       f                    \\\hline
                      f   &        f                   \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Category4}              \\\hline
                   f      &        f                   \\\hline
                   f      &        f                   \\\hline
                    f     &        f                   \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Category5} \\\hline
                     f    &       f                    \\\hline
                     f    &        f                  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
 \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Category5} \\\hline
```

use `\multicolumn{2}{|l|}` instead of `\multicolumn{2}{l}`.